# not able to send email while user creation

Tags: django, django-views, sendmail, django-signals

I'm trying to put send a random 6 digit otp through email .Below code work for django 4.0 but not working in 3.2 ,
I'm not getting any error but when i createsuperuser in django 4.0 setup email send work but not the case in django 3.2

views.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def send_email_otp(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            subject = "Your email needs to be verified to use this site"
            message = f'Hi, Dear {instance.name} use this following OTP to Get verified your email : OTP({instance.otpForEmail})/'

            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [instance.email]
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
            print(f"Email Sent to {instance.email}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Something Wrong at send_email_otp")
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from .models import CustomUser


def updateUser(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if user.email != '':
        user.name = user.email


pre_save.connect(updateUser, sender=CustomUser)
```

I'm not sure what can be the problem,please help me to identify and fix .

Edit:
my email backend

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@gmail.com' #Allow Secure connections is enabled
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: What is your EMAIL_BACKEND set to in your settings?  If you don't have your email backend set to a valid SMTP server with credentials, email will not dispatch.

The Django Email Console backend is what I use for development purposes.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#console-backend

Comment: @JoeHoward I added the email backend, seems correct for now i guess

Comment: @JoeHoward Again this function works in django 4.0 but not in 3.2